AppManager throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.attach.display.DisplayService on startup
The example project is almost a copy-paste from the samples.
Using the following main class:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private AppManager app = AppManager.initialize();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        app.start(stage); // line 14
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

module-info:
module hellofx {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    
    requires com.gluonhq.charm.glisten;
    
    exports org.openjfx;
}

build.gradle:
plugins {
  id "application" 
  id "org.openjfx.javafxplugin" version "+"
  id "org.beryx.jlink" version "+"
  id "com.gluonhq.gluonfx-gradle-plugin" version "+"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:6.2.3"
}

javafx {
    version = "23"
    modules = [ "javafx.controls" ]
}

gluonfx {
//  target = "ios"  // uncomment to deploy on iOS
//  target = "android"  // uncomment to deploy on Android

    attachConfig {
        version = "4.0.21"
        services "display", "lifecycle", "statusbar", "storage"
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = "org.openjfx.MainApp"
    mainModule = "hellofx"
}

jlink {
    options = ["--strip-debug", "--compress", "2", "--no-header-files", "--no-man-pages"]
    launcher {
        name = "hellofx"
    }
}

The project builds fine both in Gradle and the IDE. Executing gradlew run or launching from the IDE gives the runtime error:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gluonhq/attach/display/DisplayService
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.2.3/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.DeviceSettings.hasNotch(DeviceSettings.java:27)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.2.3/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.DeviceSettings.setup(DeviceSettings.java:45)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.2.3/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.DeviceSettings.dedicatedSetup(DeviceSettings.java:38)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.2.3/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar.<init>(AppBar.java:127)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten@6.2.3/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.start(AppManager.java:258)
    at hellofx/org.openjfx.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@23/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.attach.display.DisplayService
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 15 more
Exception running application org.openjfx.MainApp

app.start(stage) is the line that requires the class down the line. Using a regular Application without AppManager doesn't have this issue.

You need to add requires com.gluonhq.attach.display to the module-info ?

@JoséPereda That removed that error. Then I needed to add requires com.gluonhq.attach.storage and then it worked. I don't understand why I should need to specify these myself if I don't use their classes directly. If there's an internal dependency of glisten on these, I shouldn't need to take care of it. Other modules I requires don't also require me to requires their dependencies.

Right, Glisten has a static reference to Attach modules (so those are not added by Glisten to your project in runtime). However, you are adding the Attach services to your project (via gluonfx plugin), so you need them in your module descriptor.

@JoséPereda I'm curious why they were made static. Is it because you assume whoever runs glisten will also run attach? Now my next step of running jlink runs into a new error: java.lang.module.FindException: Two versions of module com.gluonhq.attach.lifecycle found (lifecycle-4.0.21.jar and lifecycle-4.0.21-desktop.jar). I can ask a new question about this one if it's better.

gluonfx adds the desktop version or the mobile version, depending on the target. If you are going to build a native image, the plugin orders those dependencies giving priority to the classifier, and there is no issue with duplicated modules. However, for jlink you don't need the gluonfx plugin at all... do you?

@JoséPereda No, but I target several platforms with the same app. For desktop I want to create a jlink image (not a native image). For mobile I have to create a native bundle with gluonfx. I can pass in the target when I build, but the default should be Desktop (host - where I'm building), so I don't see why there are 2 modules. One has the desktop classifier, the other has none.

Attach has two modules per service: one with the API, the other (the one with the classifier) with the native implementation (for desktop but mainly mobile). The first one is used on desktop to run on the JVM. For jlink you might need to exclude one or the other (the desktop version for Lifecycle has no much use: https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/lifecycle/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/attach/lifecycle/impl/DesktopLifecycleService.java)

@JoséPereda Good to know. I tried now to just remove lifecycle from the services list and that was enough to get it to compile and run. I think I will just pass the list of services depending on the target platform (I need to pass the target configuration anyway). Makes sense, no?
